Corrections for introducing a bain marie to a cheesecake recipe
I've got a lot of great recipes for cheesecakes.  Some require the use of a bain marie and some don't.
I have this one recipe which does not require one.  It calls to cool the cake in the closed, turned-off oven overnight.
Unfortunately it cracks terribly.  I can't help but think if I used a water bath that it would correct the cracking.
If I introduce a water bath to a recipe that doesn't call for it, what corrections do I need to make to the recipe?
For more information, here is the firing schedule for this one cheesecake:

bake at 425 F for 15 mins
reduce oven to 275 F and bake for an additional hour
turn off the heat and let the cake cool in the oven overnight

